# Picking a Random Object in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say I have an array with objects, *1, 2, 3 and 4.*
How would I pick a random object from this array?

Comment: All answers here are correct, but for more up-to-date solution see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837462/730701). It uses the `arc4random_uniform` method to avoid modulo bias.

Comment: not an answer for this question, but an interesting point - other Foundation collections (NSSet NSHashTable) have methods "anyObject" that read an arbitrary (random) object from the Set/HashTable. One could implement this method in an extension  to NSArray, following suggestions below.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

@Darryl's answer is correct, but could use some minor tweaks:

```
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % theArray.count;
```

Modifications:

- Using `arc4random()` over `rand()` and `random()` is simpler because it does not require seeding (calling `srand()` or `srandom()`).
- The [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator) (`%`) makes the overall statement shorter, while also making it semantically clearer.

Comment: From arc4random man page: arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Comment: @collibhoy no, because `0 % 4 = 0`, `1 % 4 = 1`, `2 % 4 = 2`, `3 % 4 = 3`, `4 % 4 = 0`, `5 % 4 = 1`... If you modulo by *n*, your largest result will never be greater than *n-1*.

Comment: @DaveDeLong According to the source code, ```count``` is a property: ```@interface NSArray<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding, NSFastEnumeration>

@property (readonly) NSUInteger count;```

Answer (score 17):

This is the simplest solution I could come up with:

```
id object = array.count == 0 ? nil : array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```

It's necessary to check `count` because a non-`nil` but empty `NSArray` will return `0` for `count`, and `arc4random_uniform(0)` returns `0`. So without the check, you'll go out of bounds on the array.

This solution is tempting but is **wrong** because it will cause a crash with an empty array:

```
id object = array[arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```

For reference, here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html):

```
u_int32_t
arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound);

arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.
```

The man page doesn't mention that `arc4random_uniform` returns `0` when `0` is passed as `upper_bound`.

Also, `arc4random_uniform` is defined in `<stdlib.h>`, but adding the `#import` wasn't necessary in my iOS test program.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
NSUInteger randomIndex = (NSUInteger)floor(random()/RAND_MAX * [theArray count]);
```

Don't forget to initialize the random number generator (srandomdev(), for example).

NOTE: I've updated to use -count instead of dot syntax, per the answer below.

Answer (score 9):

```
@interface NSArray<ObjectType>  (Random)
- (nullable ObjectType)randomObject;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Random)

- (nullable id)randomObject
{
    id randomObject = [self count] ? self[arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)[self count])] : nil;
    return randomObject;
}

@end
```

Edit: Updated for Xcode 7. Generics, nullability

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random number and use it as the index. Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
        NSUInteger randomNumber;
        int fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd != -1) {
            read(fd, &randomNumber, sizeof(randomNumber));
            close(fd);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open /dev/random: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        double scaledRandomNumber = ((double)randomNumber)/NSUIntegerMax * [array count];
        NSUInteger randomIndex = (NSUInteger)floor(scaledRandomNumber);
        NSLog(@"random element: %@", [array objectAtIndex: randomIndex]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Joshua if you want a little more detail, you can use `SecRandomCopyBytes()` to get cryptographically-useful random numbers, on the iPhone anyway. On Mac you have direct access to /dev/random.

Comment: I think the main point of the question is to show how to pick a random item from the array, and this answer doesn't really give the best information.

Comment: I quite like this joke, but I voted it down to aid those who don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 srand([[NSDate date]  timeIntervalSince1970]);

 int inx =rand()%[array count];
```

inx is the random number.

where srand() can be anywhere in the program before the random picking function.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectType *objectVarName = [array objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((int)(array.count - 1))];
```

if you want to cast that to an int, here's the solution for that (useful for when you need a random int from an array of non-sequential numbers, in the case of randomizing an enum call, etc)

```
int intVarName = (int)[(NSNumber *)[array objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((int)(array.count - 1))] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4:

```
let array = ["one","two","three","four"]
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count))

array[Int(randomNumber)]
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it improves on the many answers this 7-year-old question already has