# selecting a random objectAtIndex from NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsarray

I have an NSArray which contains 10 objects from index 0 - 9.  Each entry in the array is a quotation.

When my user selects the 'random quote' option I want to be able to select a random entry from the array and display the text that is contained in that entry.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picking a Random Object in an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend you use this instead of hardcoding the 10; that way, if you add more quotations, it will work it out automatically, without you needing to change that number.

```
NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random()%[array count];
NSString *quote = [array objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your probably going to want to use arc4random() to pick an object from 0-9. Then, simply do

```
NSString* string = [array objectAtIndex:randomPicked];
```

to get the text of the entry.

Comment: Perfect. I had managed to get the random number using arc4random() but was having trouble extracting the text. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arc4random()%10` to get an index.  There is a slight bias that should not be a problem.

Better yet use `arc4random_uniform(10)`, there is no bias and is even easier to use.

Comment: Hey, I thought you had a security background! `arc4random_uniform` has no bias and should be used here.

Comment: Right, `arc4random_uniform()` is the correct function to use. I did mention a slight bias and for mod 10 the bias is miniscule. I have added a correcting addendum.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a random number between your bounds, see [this discussion](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) and the relevant man pages.  Then just index into the array with it.

```
int random_number = rand()%10; // Or whatever other method.
return [quote_array objectAtIndex:random_number];
```

---

Edit: for those who can't properly interpolate from the links or just don't care to read suggested references, let me spell this out for you:

```
// Somewhere it'll be included when necessary, 
// probably the header for whatever uses it most.
#ifdef DEBUG 
#define RAND(N) (rand()%N)
#else 
#define RAND(N) (arc4random()%N)
#endif

...

// Somewhere it'll be called before RAND(), 
// either appDidLaunch:... in your application delegate 
// or the init method of whatever needs it.
#ifdef DEBUG
// Use the same seed for debugging 
// or you can get errors you have a hard time reproducing.
srand(42);
#else
// Don't seed arc4random()
#endif

....

// Wherever you need this.
NSString *getRandomString(NSArray *array) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
    // I highly suggest this, 
    // but if you don't want to put it in you don't have to.
    assert(array != nil);
    #endif
    int index = RAND([array count]);
    return [array objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: It is best to use arc4random().  If no seed is provided the sam sequence will be returned each run of the app.

Comment: @CocoaFu First of all, that's why I linked the discussion and referred to the man pages, and noted variable random method in the code sample.  Second, have you ever tried to debug a program with a different seed each time?

Comment: Until you get to the point where this part is quite thoroughly debugged and working, yes.  When it's working with one stream, then you can go and try others.  Regardless, picking a fortune doesn't need crypto-level randomness.  Customers aren't going to record a million selections and complain about a 1/1,000,000 bias.