# Random selection in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Picking a Random Object in an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray)

How to select the random item from an array

```
  NSMutableArray *array= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", @"fourth",  nil];
```

What is the way to select random item from an array containing n number of elements

Comment: do some google there are various methods available to get random data from an array and many questions similar to your questions is available on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get unique value every time use srand() with time stamp.

```
srand([[NSDate date]  timeIntervalSince1970]);
int inx =rand()%[array count];
return inx;
```

Comment: it is better placing srand at start of program and not in the random picking function itself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just get a random number between `0` and `n-1` where `n` is the number of elements. For example:

```
int i = arc4random() % [array count];
return [array objectAtIndex:i];
```