# Pick random NSNumber from an Array?

Tags: arrays, nsnumber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Picking a Random Object in an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray)

How do I pick a random NSNumber from an array containing 15 different prices (2.25, 5.99 etc)?
I want to do some calculations with them later on.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
NSNumber *n = [theArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % 15];
```