# Pick random element of NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, random, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Picking a Random Object in an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray)

I have have an array in Objective-C with strings:

```
NSArray *tips;
tips = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"Foo",
       @"Bar",
       @"Baz",
       nil];
```

I want a method that takes a random item from the array, and returns it. Is there a method, or how can I write one myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use this code:

```
uint32_t rnd = arc4random_uniform([tips count]);

NSString *randomObject = [tips objectAtIndex:rnd];
```

**EDIT:**
While working on my project i decided to create a category for NSArray. It's very simple but i found it useful.

Here are the files:

**NSArray+Random.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (Random)

- (id)randomObject;

@end
```

**NSArray+Random.m**

```
#import "NSArray+Random.h"

@implementation NSArray (Random)

-(id)randomObject {
    NSUInteger myCount = [self count];
    if (myCount)
        return [self objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(myCount)];
    else
        return nil;
}

@end
```

Then in the current example you use it like this:

```
NSString *randomObject = [tips randomObject];
```

Using category has another advantage: when you decide to change your way of selecting random objects in your app you just modify the randomObject method.

Comment: +1 because I just learned about arc4random_uniform. Thank you. Time to replace all my arc4randoms

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Glad i could help. You may want to use the category i just posted. Then your next change will be less painful :)

Comment: @Beakr You're welcome! Check my edited version though.

Comment: @Adam cool, I would call mine `sample` because of my strong bond with the Ruby language. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
NSUInteger i = arc4random();
NSString *string = [tips objectAtIndex: i];

-(NSString *) returnArrayItem: (NSArray *) array {
    //Sets randNum equal to a random number between 0 and the number of elements in the array parameter
    NSUInteger randNum = arc4random() % [array count];
    //Sets the string returnValue to a random string in the array
    NSString *returnValue =  [array objectAtIndex:randNum];
    //Returns array
    return returnValue;
}
```

Hope this helps