# Use arc4random with an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am building a theos tweak, and it needs to generate one of 4 strings randomly. It needs to pick between string add, subtract, multiply, and divide. How can it randomly choose which string to use?

Do I need to use arc4random, is there anything else? How do I use arc4random in this scenario?

This question is different than others because I did not know how to use an NSArray. I had no clue how to do it. If I knew I had to use an NSArray, I could've figured it out myself.

Comment: there is a endless number of questions and answers about picking random elements from an array.

Comment: Agreed. Please search for similar questions before posting a duplicate.

Comment: @CrimsonChris: and you could vote an answer as duplicate instead of giving an answer that is given hundreds of times.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, why don't you cast a close vote?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Couldn't find one that used arc4random_uniform. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray) is the closest thing I could find.

Comment: Ah! Here's a better [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837423/pick-random-element-of-nsarray-in-objective-c?lq=1)!

Comment: but why don't you close vote as duplicate? I see that you often comment *duplicate of …* but you never vote to close because it is a duplicate.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I flagged it as a duplicate. When you flag as a duplicate it automatically adds a comment with that "possible duplicate of" text. What do you mean by "close vote", do you mean down-vote?

Comment: no, you did not click on close -> duplicate and entered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arc4random to randomly select a value from your string array.

```
NSArray *myStrings = @[ @"add", @"subtract", @"multiply", @"divide" ];
NSUInteger randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(myArray.count);
NSString *myRandomString = myStrings[randomNumber];
```

Comment: How do I use arc4random with an NSArray?

Comment: `NSUInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % [myArray count];`. but generally you should prefer `arc4random_uniform([myArray count])`, as `arc4random()` only works well for numbers that are powers of two.