# Correct way to add images as sprites from an array

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, sprite-kit

Edited: Okay guys, the code below runs through a array and picks a sprite randomly and follows its protocols after. However, I am getting big X on the screen like if its not getting the sprites. any ideas?

```
- (void) droppedForMe {
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ball1.png",@"ball2.png",@"ball3.png", nil];
    NSUInteger arraypicker = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    for (int i=0; i < arraypicker; i++) {
            SKSpriteNode *d1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"myArray%"];
            d1.position = CGPointMake(ScalarRandomRange(d1.size.width/2, 200), self.size.height);
            SKAction *downward = [SKAction moveToY:-self.frame.size.height duration:4.0];
            [d1 runAction:downward];
            [self.items addObject:d1];
            [self addChild:d1];
        }
}
```

Comment: Be more specific about what problem you have. Is this code working? If it's not, what happens that you don't expect? If it is, why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: Here is the code. A sprite randomly positioned on X-Axis and fall but I want to have several sprites to choose from and randomly pick one and run the code below. I have updated the original question for the updated code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always selecting the "cat" sprite, you would store several sprites in an array, select a random number within the array's range and use the corresponding sprite.

Comment: NSMutableArray *sprites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"sp1", "sp2", "sp3", nil];

Hi friend so I have done this in my new code but how would I set up the random function to choose from array randomly?

Comment: @user3184143: [Picking a Random Object in an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray)

Comment: Hi all I think I got it now but one more question. in Sprite Kit for adding sprites to an array, How is it done? thanks.