# How do I select random element from an array?

Tags: objective-c

I ended up with the following plus a few modifications:

```
NSArray *Quotes = @[@"test1",@"test2"];
NSString *Quoteselected = arc4random() % [quotes];
self.label.text = Quoteselected;
```

I found the error, which probably also caused the SIGARBT -my randomization created values bigger than what I had element for in the array - thereby making the code try to pick elements not existing.

thanks for all the help

Comment: How many quotes do you have? If you have a small number there probably isn't a need for an actual database.  You can use the built-in load and save functions in `NSArray` to make your life easy.

Comment: Well I'm just starting now. But I'd guess starting with something like 50 and then gradually increasing the size of the collection

Comment: Unless you have tens of thousands you probably don't need a database.  Can you add more information on the format of your quotes (in a file I assume) and what you've tried?

Comment: Will look into NSArray functions, as I haven't been there yet. Optimistic that I can get this working.

Comment: I looked in this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/10837423/pick-random-element-of-nsarray-in-objective-c

And now I have:
uint32_t rnd = arc4random_uniform([Quotes count[);
NSString *randomObject = [Quotes objectAtIndex:rnd];
self.label.text ) randomObject;

Unfortunately in the simulator my app is black screen and I get a SIGABRT error

Comment: Sorry that I can't make an answers, so I can make breaks between the code lines, but I don't have enough reps

Comment: I'm very thankful for the answers provided. For now though I prefer to make the simple solution with NSArray work. Please give me some inputs on why my code doesn't work

Comment: @Simon Your new question has been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray

Comment: It's still unclear. When I see a question saying "it's not working" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" or "unclear what you're asking" (or in this case, to leave closed) 9 times out of 9. "It doesn't work" doesn't give anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you receive.

Comment: Problem here:
I stated a problem, wrote a bit back and forth, then found the solution - then couldn't answer my own question to help others(because I was completely new) and therefore changed the question field to write what I did... Now I have downvotes and can't ask questions... Because I was trying to give people an answer to this, instead of just leaving the thread to itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you look for:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

This is called core data that comes with Objective-C. It is what I use for small, **LOCAL** database.

On the other hand, for small to medium size of database for a starter like you (I presume you just started making programs?) Check out **ruby on rails** and **AFNetworking** library. BTW, this is **ONLINE** or **REMOTE** databse. (Just saying, but in ruby on rails, database can be created with using command line, you'll know how simple it is)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Two options, you can choose either one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're okay with typing out every quote, you could use a property list

[plist tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-13-using-property-lists-plists/)

Unless it's a very large database