# Objective-C equal distribution from 5 different NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, equals

This is my code but its still not correct. Currently i can distribute like this: 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 but i will distribute it 0,1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2 (0,1,2 are the groups)

```
//Create x Groups
for (int z=0; z<numberOfGroups; z++) {
    mutableArrayOfSubarrays[z] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:countOfElementsForTheGroups];
}
int nextSubarray = 0;

//Distribute the Objects into the groups
    for (int i = 0; i < [AllObjectsToDistribute count]; i++)
    {

      [mutableArrayOfSubarrays[nextSubarray] addObject:[AllObjectsToDistribute objectAtIndex:i]];
      nextSubarray = nextSubarray % customGroups;
      nextSubarray++;
      nextSubarray = nextSubarray  % customGroups;
        }
```

Comment: See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318902/picking-a-random-object-in-an-nsarray

Please don't post questions without your own code, it looks like homework.

Comment: The example doesn't add up, 6 objects picked from NSMutablearray3 (c), b3 is picked twice. Is the number of arrays or groups fixed? Did you try anything? Instead of picking a random object it might be easier to shuffle the arrays.

Comment: Oh sorry its my mistake. The number of groups are not fixed. user can set the number of created groups. pre-condition is number of groups <= number of objects to distribute. the current status is: i can randomly fill the groups but this is not what i need.

Comment: 1. Shuffle the array's. 2. Join the arrays in one big array. 3. Distribute the big array over the groups, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3 etc. Maybe SQLite can do step 1 and 2.

Comment: step 1. and 2. is already done but the disribution is my problem :( i have edit the question and add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which way the group index counts in a BOOL.
Example:

```
NSUInteger groupIndex = 0;
BOOL groupIndexCountsUp = YES;
for (id object in allObjectsToDistribute) {
    [groupsArray[groupIndex] addObject:object];
    if (groupIndexCountsUp) {
        if (groupIndex < numberOfGroups - 1)
            groupIndex++;
        else
            groupIndexCountsUp = NO;
    }
    else {
        if (groupIndex > 0)
            groupIndex--;
        else
            groupIndexCountsUp = YES;
    }
}
```